# Examples of oblivious transfer protocols secure under stronger security assumptions than semi-honest model?

Tags: multiparty-computation, oblivious-transfer

The question is basically stated on the title. I have done some introductory reading on Oblivious Transfer and most of them are secure in the semi-honest model. Are there any protocols that are secure under stronger security assumptions (e.g. malicious adversaries) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there are, e.g. CO15: The Simplest Protocol for Oblivious Transfer (https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/267.pdf) is actively secure.